# Currency identifier doesn't display until something is typed into input

Tags: javascript

My currency converter currently only shows the appropriate currency identifier behind the output once something has been typed in the input box

The thing I thought to be most logical, adding

```
${selectedCountry.country_method}
```

to the **first** if statement

```
const calculate = () => {
    const output_we_sell = document.getElementById("output_we_sell");
    if (amount.value === '') {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `0.00`; // In this line
        return;
    }
    if (!isNaN(amount.value)) {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `${amount.value * selectedMethod.we_sell * selectedCountry.rate.toFixed(2)} ${selectedCountry.country_method}`;
    }
};
```

breaks the entire script

How do I go about getting the appropriate currency to display behind the 0.00 before anything has been inputted by the user?

JS:

```js
const data = [
    {
        method: 'paypal',
        we_buy: 0.50,
        we_sell: 0.68,
        img_path: 'img/paypal.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-paypal'
    },
    {
        method: 'debit',
        we_buy: 0.67,
        we_sell: 0.82,
        img_path: 'img/debit-card.svg',
        icon: 'far fa-credit-card'
    },
    {
        method: 'btc',
        we_buy: 0.58,
        we_sell: 0.77,
        img_path: 'img/bitcoin.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-btc'
    },
    {
        method: 'ethereum',
        we_buy: 0.59,
        we_sell: 0.76,
        img_path: 'img/ethereum.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-ethereum'
    }
];

const country = [
    {
        country_id: 'USA',
        country_method: 'USD',
        img_path: 'img/united-states.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign',
        rate: 1.00
    },
    {
        country_id: 'UK',
        country_method: 'GBP',
        img_path: 'img/united-kingdom.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-pound-sign',
        rate: 0.78
    },  
    {
        country_id: 'EUR',
        country_method: 'EUR',
        img_path: 'img/european-union.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-euro-sign',
        rate: 0.88
    },
    {
        country_id: 'CAN',
        country_method: 'CAD',
        img_path: 'img/canada.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign',
        rate: 1.33
    },
    {
        country_id: 'AUS',
        country_method: 'AUD',
        img_path: 'img/australia.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign',
        rate: 1.40
    }
];

const countryContainer = document.getElementById("countries");
let selectedCountry = null;
var selectCountry = function (index) {
    const cdata = country[index];
    selectedCountry = country[index];
    document.getElementById("country-selected").innerHTML = `Country selected: ${cdata.country_method}`;
    document.getElementById("country_icon").className = cdata.icon;
};

// Image container

const imagesContainer = document.getElementById("methods");
let selectedMethod = null;
var selectMethod = function (index) {
    const element = data[index];
    selectedMethod = data[index];
    document.getElementById("method-selected").innerHTML = `Method selected: ${element.method}`;
    document.getElementById("data_icon").className = element.icon; 
};

// made function originally in amount.onkeyup have a greater scope
function clearInvalid() {
    var input = document.getElementById('amount')
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')
  }
const calculate = () => {
    const output_we_sell = document.getElementById("output_we_sell");
    if (amount.value === '') {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = '0.00';
        return;
    }
    if (!isNaN(amount.value)) {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `${((+amount.value * selectedMethod.we_sell) * selectedCountry.rate).toFixed(2)} ${(selectedCountry.country_method)}`;
    }
};
// ...
var selectMethod = function (index) {
    const element = data[index];
    selectedMethod = data[index];
    document.getElementById("method-selected").innerHTML = `Method selected: ${element.method}`;
    document.getElementById("data_icon").className = element.icon;
    calculate(); // Added calculate here
};

var selectCountry = function (index) {
    const cdata = country[index];
    selectedCountry = country[index];
    document.getElementById("country-selected").innerHTML = `Method selected: ${cdata.country}`;
    document.getElementById("country_icon").className = cdata.icon;
    calculate();
};

// ...
(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        imagesContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="method" onclick=selectMethod(${i})><img id=${i} src=${data[i].img_path}></div>`;
    }
    selectMethod(0);
    selectCountry(0);
    const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    amount.onkeyup = calculate; // Changed this to use the calculate function{
    for (let i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        countryContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="country" onclick=selectCountry(${i})><img id=${i} src=${country[i].img_path}></div>`; 
    };
}


)();
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="methods-container" data-aos="fade-right">
            <div class="method-info">
                <h2>So... You want to buy some gold?</h2>
                <p>Use our conversion rate calculator</p>
            </div>
            <div class="countries" id="countries">

            </div>
            <div class="country-selected" id="country-selected">
                No country selected.
            </div>

            <div class="methods" id="methods">

            </div>
            <div class="method-selected" id="method-selected">
                No method selected.
            </div>

            <div class="output">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i id="data_icon"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="5" onkeypress='clearInvalid()' class="form-control" aria-label="Amount of GP in Millions" placeholder="Amount of Gold" id="amount">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i id="country_icon"></i></span>
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="output_we_sell"></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeLeJm

Comment: What's the error when the script "breaks"? Can you share the code that doesn't work as opposed to the code that does?

Comment: it just makes everything disappear off the page when I add `${selectedCountry.country_method}` to `if (amount.value === '') {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `0.00`; // In this line`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: added codepen @melpomene

Comment: @Zee *Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included __in the question itself__*, not a "codepen". Also, that code is far from minimal. You've got nearly 10k of CSS alone there.

Comment: The CSS isn't really relevant though, it's just to give a general gist of what things are meant to look like. I keep getting told off for putting too much code on here whenever I ask a question and now I'm not adding enough? This community's guidelines are such a blur

Comment: If the CSS isn't relevant to the problem at hand, don't post it. As the link explains, you need to make sure we can reproduce the problem, so all relevant code should be posted as part of the question. It should also be minimal, so when you've put together an example that demonstrates the issue you're having, try removing parts of it to see if the problem still occurs. If so, you've found code that doesn't affect the problem and you can remove it. Keep going until you have a small program that is still runnable.

Comment: For example, your current code doesn't reproduce the problem you're talking about because nothing actually calls `calculate`, and the HTML code uses `clearInvalid()`, which isn't defined.

Comment: Added the whole script

Comment: I get `TypeError: selectedCountry is null` with `\`0.00 ${selectedCountry.country_method}\``.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194722/discussion-between-zee-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem all you need to do is change the order of two functions:

Run selectCountry before selectmethod:

```
selectCountry(0);
selectMethod(0);
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        method: 'paypal',
        we_buy: 0.50,
        we_sell: 0.68,
        img_path: 'img/paypal.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-paypal'
    },
    {
        method: 'debit',
        we_buy: 0.67,
        we_sell: 0.82,
        img_path: 'img/debit-card.svg',
        icon: 'far fa-credit-card'
    },
    {
        method: 'btc',
        we_buy: 0.58,
        we_sell: 0.77,
        img_path: 'img/bitcoin.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-btc'
    },
    {
        method: 'ethereum',
        we_buy: 0.59,
        we_sell: 0.76,
        img_path: 'img/ethereum.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-ethereum'
    }
];

const country = [
    {
        country_id: 'USA',
        country_method: 'USD',
        img_path: 'img/united-states.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign',
        rate: 1.00
    },
    {
        country_id: 'UK',
        country_method: 'GBP',
        img_path: 'img/united-kingdom.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-pound-sign',
        rate: 0.78
    },  
    {
        country_id: 'EUR',
        country_method: 'EUR',
        img_path: 'img/european-union.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-euro-sign',
        rate: 0.88
    },
    {
        country_id: 'CAN',
        country_method: 'CAD',
        img_path: 'img/canada.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign',
        rate: 1.33
    },
    {
        country_id: 'AUS',
        country_method: 'AUD',
        img_path: 'img/australia.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign',
        rate: 1.40
    }
];

const countryContainer = document.getElementById("countries");
let selectedCountry = null;
var selectCountry = function (index) {
    const cdata = country[index];
    selectedCountry = country[index];
    document.getElementById("country-selected").innerHTML = `Country selected: ${cdata.country_method}`;
    document.getElementById("country_icon").className = cdata.icon;
};

// Image container

const imagesContainer = document.getElementById("methods");
let selectedMethod = null;
var selectMethod = function (index) {
    const element = data[index];
    selectedMethod = data[index];
    document.getElementById("method-selected").innerHTML = `Method selected: ${element.method}`;
    document.getElementById("data_icon").className = element.icon; 
};

// made function originally in amount.onkeyup have a greater scope
function clearInvalid() {
    var input = document.getElementById('amount')
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')
  }
const calculate = () => {
    const output_we_sell = document.getElementById("output_we_sell");
    if (amount.value === '') {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `0.00 ${(selectedCountry.country_method)}`;
        return;
    }
    if (!isNaN(amount.value)) {
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `${((+amount.value * selectedMethod.we_sell) * selectedCountry.rate).toFixed(2)} ${(selectedCountry.country_method)}`;
    }
};
// ...
var selectMethod = function (index) {
    const element = data[index];
    selectedMethod = data[index];
    document.getElementById("method-selected").innerHTML = `Method selected: ${element.method}`;
    document.getElementById("data_icon").className = element.icon;
    calculate(); // Added calculate here
};

var selectCountry = function (index) {
    const cdata = country[index];
    selectedCountry = country[index];
    document.getElementById("country-selected").innerHTML = `Method selected: ${cdata.country}`;
    document.getElementById("country_icon").className = cdata.icon;
    calculate();
};

// ...
(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        imagesContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="method" onclick=selectMethod(${i})><img id=${i} src=${data[i].img_path}></div>`;
    }
    
    selectCountry(0);
    selectMethod(0);
    const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    amount.onkeyup = calculate; // Changed this to use the calculate function{
    for (let i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        countryContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="country" onclick=selectCountry(${i})><img id=${i} src=${country[i].img_path}></div>`; 
    };
}


)();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="methods-container" data-aos="fade-right">
            <div class="method-info">
                <h2>So... You want to buy some gold?</h2>
                <p>Use our conversion rate calculator</p>
            </div>
            <div class="countries" id="countries">

            </div>
            <div class="country-selected" id="country-selected">
                No country selected.
            </div>

            <div class="methods" id="methods">

            </div>
            <div class="method-selected" id="method-selected">
                No method selected.
            </div>

            <div class="output">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i id="data_icon"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="5" onkeypress='clearInvalid()' class="form-control" aria-label="Amount of GP in Millions" placeholder="Amount of Gold" id="amount">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i id="country_icon"></i></span>
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="output_we_sell"></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```